# PHP Open Multiple Connections

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I would like to run multiple scripts instances of the same script in different browser tabs. And I would like them to have different MySQL connections. Each its unique connection.

I know that [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) has a fourth parameter `$new_link` which should open a new link, but even that does not open a new connection, usually. Sometimes it does.

I have a XAMPP install on a Widows machine.

The question is: How can I absolutely force PHP/MySQL to open a new connections for each instance of a script? Script runs for about 2mins.

`http://localhost/myscript.php`

Here are the excerpts of the MySQL code. First load a work assignment from DB and mark it as in progress:

```
public function loadRange() {
    try{
        $this->db()->query('START TRANSACTION');
        $this->row = $this->db()->getObject("
            SELECT * FROM {$this->tableRanges}
            WHERE
                status = " . self::STATUS_READY_FOR_WORK . "
                AND domain_id = {$this->domainId}
            ORDER BY sort ASC
            LIMIT 1");
        if(!$this->row) throw new Exception('Could not load range');
        $this->db()->update($this->tableRanges, $this->row->id, array(
            'thread_id' => $this->id,
            'status' => self::STATUS_WORKING,
            'run_name' => $this->runName,
            'time_started' => time(),
        ));
        $this->db()->query('COMMIT');
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->db()->query('ROLLBACK');
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then the script may or may not INSERT rows in another table based on what it finds.

In the end, when task is finished, the assignment row is UPDATEd again:

```
    $this->db()->update($this->tableRanges, $this->row->id, array(
        'status' => self::STATUS_EXECUTED,
        'time_finished' => time(),
        'count' => $count,
    ));
```

In particular, the `$this->tableRanges` table looks to be locked. Any idea why it is the case? It is an InnoDB table.

Comment: new connections per instance is standard behavior. are you having a specific problem you're trying to find a solution for?

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to run multiple scripts instances of the same script in different browser tabs. And I would like them to have different MySQL connections. Each its unique connection.

This is actually the case, without any additional effort

> The question is: How can I absolutely force PHP/MySQL to open a new connections for each instance of a script.

Answer: do nothing :)

Comment: Nope, script runs for about 2min, and I see that one waits for another to finish, and I see from MySQL that there is only one connection open all the time: SHOW STATUS LIKE '%onn%'

Comment: in this case, sounds your tables are locking while a sql query finishes up.

Comment: Do you use table locks? How many parrallel connection are allowed in `my.cnf` ? Are you connecting using the `root` account?

Comment: Looks like you're facing the limitations of single-threaded browsers. Try Chrome and check the script behaviour again ;)

Comment: @castis Yes, sounds to me too, but the table is InnoDB and I do START TRANSACTION, SELECT, UPDATE, COMMIT

Comment: @hek2mgl I am connecting as root, no password, localhost. max_connections is more that 1 for sure as it sometimes increases if I run the script from different browsers or run many instances at the same time.

Comment: `START TRANSACTION` should not lead to locked tables. Can you post your SQL to pastebin or somewhere? need more information

Comment: @hek2mgl I have added excerpts of the MySQL code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

every time you hit `http://localhost/myscript.php` a new instance is run. Everything about that instance is unique, the web server spawns a new PHP thread, in which all the resources, connections, variables are unique.

Only state management devices such as `sessions` are shared and that too if you are using different tabs in same browser. If you hit the same URL with different browsers, the state management resources are different too.

To answer your question, like others mentioned before - your connection is different for each instance IF you are using `mysql_connect`. You could create a persistent connection that does not close when the application exits and `reuses` it for new connection requests using `mysql_pconnect`. But in your code it seems you are using the latter and in that case, you are fine.

You can try to set the isolation read level to prevent table stalling while reading for select

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;`

[More information can be found here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html)

Again I guess it will take a bit of playing around to find which option works the best.

Comment: I run the same script in 10 tabs, I clearly see that one waits for another, I clearly see phpMyAdmin that there is usually only one connection open.

Comment: @jQguru, why that happens has nothing to do with the connections. Even if you have totally different connections, if you are having parallel scripts even from different machines trying operations on the same table, then the table gets locked. There are variations as to table level or row level locking based on the kind of operation being done. This has nothing to do with new or existing connection..

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I have posted MySQL relevant excerpts of the script in the question. Could something there possibly lock the table.

Comment: If you do a select *, then the table will stall on inserts until the select is completed. This is because MySQL cannot update while select is running. While setting transaction you can add additional parameters to control level of locking. Check update in my answer